# Facebook profile picture & name from App Scoped ID with Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use a Facebook Friend Picker in my iOS application. When I pick a friend I will only get a App Scoped ID but I need the Facebook ID to get the profile picture and name from that friend.

Is it possible to convert the App Scoped ID to the normal Facebook ID or retrieve that data with the App Scoped ID?

I read a lot about it https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids but can't find a solution.

**UPDATE**

I'm trying to get the profile picture like this (worked before with the normal Facebook ID):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large&access_token={access_token}|{secret}", item.giftID]];
NSData *tempData =  [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url] returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

I would then put the `tempData` in an `UIImageView` like this:

```
UIImageView *profilePic = (UIImageView *)[myCell viewWithTag:1];
profilePic.image = [UIImage imageWithData:tempData];
```

But this doesn't seems to work with the new API call, any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: if it would be possible to convert a scoped id to a global one, there would be no need for a scoped id at all...

Comment: I know but I can't get the profile picture of the friend that I've selected just by his App Scoped ID, I need his real Facebook ID for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found another way of retrieving the Profile Picture with the Scoped App ID, it was pretty easy after all.

```
http://graph.facebook.com/ScopedAddID/picture?type=normal
```

This code did the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the user's name or picture by using your App ID and Secret in the API Call:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{app_scoped_id}?fields=name,picture&access_token={app_id}|{app_secret}
```

This will give you the requested details for the user, for example:

```
{
   "name": "Niraj Shah",
   "picture": {
      "data": {
         "is_silhouette": false,
         "url": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xap1/v/t1.0-1/c58.40.500.500/s50x50/18400_10100210273961696_245749691_n.jpg?oh=42982af99b925b1167e52f82eb8316c3&oe=5485298D&__gda__=1418016600_1e8a22c1ac6366f6dbad85990c817e65"
      }
   },
   "id": "10100392436431646"
}
```

Comment: Your API call seems to be working in the browser so thanks for that but it's not yet working with my code I used when I had the normal Facebook ID, I've updated my answer.

Comment: The same call can be used for User IDs that are not app scoped (i.e. normal user IDs). The API call is backwards compatible as specified in the Facebook Migration documentation.